# solutions exist on$ [0,∞)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, control-theory

Consider the system

$x' = y − x^3$

$y' = -0.5\,x − y + d\sin(t)$

where $d$ is a constant. Show that all solutions exist on $[0,\infty)$.
I'm trying to show that any solution is bounded, by showing that the function $x(t)^2 + y(t)^2$ is decreasing. But I end up with $4\,d\,y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $V=\frac12x^2+y^2$ as Lyapunov function. Then
\begin{align}
\dot V f&=x(y-x^3)+2y(-0.5x-y+d\sin(t))=-x^4-2y^2+2dy\sin(t)
\\
&\le -x^4-y^2+d^2=-V-\left(x^2-\frac14\right)^2+d^2+\frac14
\end{align}
using $2dy\sin(t)\le y^2+d^2\sin^2(t)\le y^2+d^2$.

Now consider the region $V>1+d^2$ to get that the vector field is inward pointing. Or use directly that along trajectories in that direction
$$
V(x(t))\le e^{-(t-t_0)}V(x(t_0))+\left(d^2+\frac14\right)\left(1-e^{-(t-t_0)}\right).
$$

Comment: +1: Nice, I didn't know that one can use Lyapunov functions for the existence of solutions. Could you explain what has to be shown in order for the proof to be valid?

Comment: You get existence from the differentiability of the ODE. As no solution can leave $\{(x,y):V(x,y)<\max(V(x_0,y_0),d^2+\frac14)\}$ for positive times, the maximal solution has no upper bound for its defining interval.